# Using Indirect to Average an Array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A2 |
| 2 | A3 |
| 3 | A4 |

I am trying to average a list of numbers that have a variable address.  I created a very simple example to try it, but I haven't figured out how to do it.  In the example above, I would like to reference the cell addresses in column B in order to average the numbers in column A. In the real thing I'm trying to do, the addresses in column B are variable (and refer to different tabs) and the number is variable as well.  I hope I explained this correctly.  Any insights would be appreciated.  Thank you.

I tried creating an array with the values in column B, and then using INDIRECT, but INDIRECT doesn't work with an array. I just keep getting errors.

Comment: Google sheets (among others) have similarities to Microsoft's Excel.  You may wish to look into Excel as well.

Comment: `(and refer to different tabs)` what do mean by this line? `BYROW()`, `MAP()` may work with array and indirect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ARRAYFORMULA`

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(INDIRECT(B2:B4)))
```

Use [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en)

```cpp
=AVERAGE(MAP(B2:B4,LAMBDA(ref,INDIRECT(ref))))
```

[image]